LaTeX - start new chapter on same page - scrreprt
I am using scrreprt document class. When I create a new chapter, it starts it on a new blank page.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
I want to be able to start new chapters on the same page as the old chapter ends. Is there any way to do it?
I already tried:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

or
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{\vfil\if@twoside\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\fi\if@tempswa\twocolumn\fi}
\makeatother

There is a similar question using the book documentclass: Start new chapter on same page
unfortunately the solutions presented there don't resolve this issue.
I would appreciate any help.

Test document code:
main.tex:
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{test}
\date{December 2024}
\raggedbottom 



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\end{document}

chapter1.tex:

\chapter{chapter1}
chapter1lorem
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\section{section1}
section1lorem

chapter2.tex

\chapter{chapter2}
chapter2lorem


As already asked on SO, please include a compilable test document.

If you want \chapter to behave more like a \section you don't need to patch anything in KOMA-Script classes scrbook and scrreprt. KOMA-Script classes provide the command \RedeclareSectionCommand to change the style of every sectioning command including \part and \chapter. So a simple:
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}

is enough to remove the typical clear page behave of \chapter.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}

\usepackage{mwe}% For demonstration.

\title{test}
\date{December 2024}
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\blindtext

\chapter{Second chapter}

\blindtext

\blinddocument

\end{document}


Note also the difference of \include and \input, i.e., that \include always starts a new page. Therefore you should not use \include (but \input), if you don't want the new file to start a new page.
BTW: If you want, that only some \chapter behave different, please have a look at scrbook - Part and Chapter on same page.
For more information on \RedeclareSectionCommand, the available styles and all the other available configuration options see the KOMA-Script documentation (in English or German), currently section 20.8.
Note, in the Wiki articles How to prevent chapters from starting a new page and Wie verhindert werden kann, dass Kapitel eine neue Seite beginnen the KOMA-Script author also recommends, shows and explains a solution as shown in this answer.

I figured it out!
By adding the following code:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

in addition to using \input instead of \include to load new .tex files will resolve the issue!
Thank you,
e4e5Ke2

fixed main.tex:
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{test}
\date{December 2024}
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}

\end{document}


I cannot recommend to patch an internal command instead of using the official user interface. This can easily fail after any change of the internals of the class.
